# modal box on click of submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a web app that gives the articles for the german nouns enter by the user.
I've written the code where the noun will be accepted by the user and the article from the database will be displayed in a modal box.
But the modal box doesn't stay. Further the first time i click on the submit button the else section runs even though the word exists in the database.

here's the code:

```html
<!-- Parallax Image with noun Text -->
<div class="bgimg-2 w3-display-container w3-opacity-min">
  <div class="w3-display-middle">
    <span class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-white w3-wide">NOUN</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Container (noun Section) -->
<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" id="noun">
  <h3 class="w3-center">ENTER THE NOUN: </h3></br></br>
  <form name="logged_in.jsp" method="post" action="">
  <div class="w3-center">
          <input type="text" name="noun"></br></br></br>
  </div>

   
  
    <div class="w3-center">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-right w3-section" type="submit" id="article" >
          GET ARTICLE 
        </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  
</div>


<!-- The Modal -->
 <div id="nounModal" class="modal"> 
     <% String s =null;
         String s1=request.getParameter("noun");
           String s2 =null;
           String s3 =null;
           int f=0;
         try{
        System.out.println(s1);
          Statement st = con.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from nouns where noun='"+s1+"'");
          
           if(rs.next()){
              f=1;
             s=rs.getString("article");
             s2=rs.getString("plural");
             s3=rs.getString("meaning");
           }
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("e.............."+e);}
  
      if(f==1){%>
     

         <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
            <div id="output">
              <p>Article: <%=s%></br></p>
             <p>Noun: <%=s1%></br></p>
             <p>Plural: <%=s2%></br></p>
             <p>Meaning: <%=s3%></p>
           
           </div>
     <%}
     else{%>
     <div class="modal-content"> 
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
             <p>Sorry! no results found.
                would you like to add a new word? <a>add</a> click here
             </p>
                
            
     <%}%>
   
     </div >

</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#article").click(function(){
       $("#nounModal").modal('');
    });
 
 </script>
```

Comment: I can see **Peter** has requested to edit this question so I hope he can read this. I would recommend you clean up the source code to make your edit suggestion worthy of accepting. A minor edit to the title and not cleaning up the main question content isn't worthy of accepting.

Answer (score 0):

your button should either contain data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nounModal" atributes.

```
<button class="w3-button w3-black w3-right w3-section" type="submit" id="article" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nounModal">GET ARTICLE </button>
```

or try $("#nounModal").modal('show');